# Simple Calculator without page reload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have two input boxes, the first input box will accept a value that will be subtracted from the value stored in a cookie.  The second input will auto generated the difference while I am typing.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: The best solution? JavaScript. If you'd like more useful answers, please provide more information. What's the mark-up of your 'calculator,' what inputs/elements are you using? Plain JavaScript, or  a library? What's the name of the variable in the cookie?

Comment: vanilla javavscript would suffice.

Comment: hello David.. sorry for mentioning the cookies.. let's say i have a variable that has an N value, then the first input box will accept a value that will be subtracted from variable N. the difference should be displayed  in the second input box

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to use **vanilla Javascript** only.

You can read **cookies** directly from Javascript:

> http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

You can make the second input **un-editable** using `readonly` attribute:

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

You can do math directly in the **`onkeyup` event** of the first input:

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: I wish I could add +2 for vanilla :)

Answer (score 0):

Hook the keyup and mouseup events on the first input box. In the handler do parseInt() on its value, if !isNaN() calculate the difference and write it to the second input box.

I don't see, why you would need ajax for a subtraction!

Answer (score 0):

As cookies can be created, read and erased by JavaScript you can accomplish this task using javascript.  As Eugen Rieck points out you can use keyup/down events.

Answer (score 0):

You only need Javascript. Use Serverside (PHP|PYTHON|JAVA|PERL) only if you need to store it on server. Or wants to show results to other people.

For your case , server side is only needed If you want to:

1. Store it on the server so other people can see it.
2. Multi User subtraction ?
3. Log what visitor did.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function subtract(first, second)
{
    total = first - second;
    obj("total").value = total;
}

function obj(id)
{
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

</script>

<input type="text" id="first" onkeyup="javascript:subtract(this.value, obj('second').value)" />
-
<input type="text" id="second" onkeyup="javascript:subtract(obj('first').value, this.value)"/>
=
<input type="text" id="total"/>
```